# Telethon asyncio type hint

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, type-hinting, telethon

I'm using **telethon** library in python. I'm trying to use type hinting to get **PyCharm** auto-complete feature work right. In code snippet below, function `filter_open_dialogs` takes return value of function [get_dialogs()](https://telethon.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telethon.client.html#telethon.client.dialogs.DialogMethods.get_dialogs) as input. Reading telethon documentation, i found out that return type of `get_dialogs()` is `TotalList` so add type hint to `dialogs` input argument. Then i tried to call function `filter_open_dialogs` :

```py
from telethon.tl.types import User
from telethon.helpers import TotalList
from telethon import TelegramClient, sync

class Crawler:

    def __init__(self, fetch: bool):

        self._client = TelegramClient('some_name', my_api_id, 'my_secret_api_hash')
        self._me = self._client.start(phone='my_phone_number', password='my_2fa_password')
        if fetch:
            self.get_open_dialogs()

    def get_open_dialogs(self):
        if self._me:
            Crawler.filter_open_dialogs(self._me.get_dialogs(), [])
            return self._me.get_dialogs()

    @staticmethod
    def filter_open_dialogs(dialogs: TotalList, filter_list: list):
        result = []
        if dialogs and dialogs.total:
            for dialog in dialogs:
                entity = dialog.entity
                if not isinstance(entity, User) and entity.id not in filter_list:
                    result.append(entity)
        return result
```

But in line `filter_open_dialogs(self._me.get_dialogs(), [])` , PyCharm shows this warning:

**Expected type TotalList', got 'Coroutine' instead ...**

Any thought what's going wrong?

Comment: It looks like `self._me.get_dialogs()` is not returning an object of type `TotalList`.

Comment: I know nothing about `telegram`, but presumably it's built around `asyncio` or another coroutine-based library, so all of these functions are actually coroutines that you're normally supposed to `await` the results rather than just using them directly? Can you give us a [mcve]?

Comment: @JohnGordon But in the code docs it says: **Same as `iter_dialogs`, but returns a`TotalList <telethon.helpers.TotalList>` instead**

Comment: @abarnert Yes that's exactly what the doc says, in new versions they are using `asyncio` but i don't know anything about it. I'll update the post with some code to be able to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Offofue Changjng a large library from synchronous or threaded or whatever to asyncio-based without radically changing the API seems like it would be a huge task, so I wouldn’t be surprised if some of the docs are lagging. If the function returns an awaitable that when awaited gives you a `TotalList`, but the docs say it directly returns a `TotalList`, that might be a docs bug that you could file and they could fix. But again, this is just a wild guess about a library I don’t know, so… hopefully someone else knows more. (But: does the code _work_, if you don’t try to type check it?)

Comment: https://telethon.readthedocs.io/en/stable/extra/basic/asyncio-magic.html

Comment: @user2357112 I've read the docs but I still can not get type hint work, any idea?

Comment: @abarnert Thanks for your help. Yes the code works without type checking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TotalList` is just a convenience class to help me return a list with a `.total` field. You probably just want to add this line:

```
from telethon.tl.custom import Dialog

def filter_open_dialogs(dialogs, filter_list):
    dialog: Dialog
    ...  # rest of code in the method
```

That should tell PyCharm to type hint correctly. I don't think you can specify the inner type of a custom class.